# What options does an international PhD student in UK have to fund his PhD?

Tags: phd, funding, united-kingdom, international-students, fees

I am in the final year of my PhD and have some dues to clear. Unfortunately, I don't have enough funds to pay my fees. What options do I have, being an international student, to obtain financial assistance to finish my degree?

Comment: Advertise yourself as a private tutor in your subject. As a PhD student you have a lot of expertise and could easily tutor GCSE, A Level or even undergraduate students. The going rate for such tutors can be as high as £20 p/h.

Comment: @astronat £20 per hour _of contact time_. An hour with a student can often require an hour of preparation, especially if it's the first time you've taught the particular course.

Comment: This is something your advisor and your department should be advising you about. It's literally their job to know about these things. Sources of funding are usually at least somewhat subject-specific but, even if you told us what you're studying, we don't take this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

- Do TA. The easiest way is to do TA for the courses that your advisor or professors in your group teach. I was paid £12.XX per hour at my school in London. As long as it is less than personal allowance (£7000 per year), you don't have to pay tax or anything, and it can be added on top of your scholarship, so it's good.
- Find an internship. My scholarship prohibited me from taking internship so I was kind of happy when it expired.
- If you major is CS, there is some programs like Google Summer of Code (open in February), which you can earn > $5000 for 3 months with no tax.

Comment: The standard tax free personal allowance in the UK is currently [£11,500](https://www.gov.uk/income-tax-rates/current-rates-and-allowances).